# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdResolver with spark 2.1.0

Tags: apache-spark

**i'm trying connect my spark (local) with S3. below is the spark configuration. while reading a file from S3 bucket using a RDD facing the below issue.**

spark 2.1.0 configuration and code snippet to read the text file from S3

```
SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().master("local")
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", accessKey)
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key",secretKey)
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3AFileSystem")
    .getOrCreate();
RDD<String> data = session.sparkContext().textFile("s3a://mybucket//filename",1);
```

error at runtime:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:200)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:194)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.registerSinks(MetricsSystem.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.start(MetricsSystem.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:522)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
at 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/ObjectIdResolver
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:543)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:448)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsServlet.<init>(MetricsServlet.scala:48)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdResolver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more

**And i also tried adding a dependencies jackson-core in POM but thrown the below error**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.BigDecimalDeserializer$.handledType()Ljava/lang/Class;
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.NumberDeserializers$.<init>(ScalaNumberDeserializersModule.scala:49)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.NumberDeserializers$.<clinit>(ScalaNumberDeserializersModule.scala)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.ScalaNumberDeserializersModule$class.$init$(ScalaNumberDeserializersModule.scala:61)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.<init>(DefaultScalaModule.scala:20)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.<init>(DefaultScalaModule.scala:37)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.<clinit>(DefaultScalaModule.scala)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:819)
```

Pom.xml

```
**

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>

**
```

need a solution to resolve this issue!, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

sadly, it looks like form of maven dependency hell. There's probably some jackson stuff coming in from spark-core, so your classpath is a mix of both. I'd recommend finding out what version that is, and then explicitly importing the jackson core/databind/annotations modules of that version.

In spark's [hadoop-cloud POM](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/hadoop-cloud/pom.xml) you can see how the jackson dependencies are stripped out from the hadoop-aws dependency, along with joda-time, and new ones declared. Try doing the same.

Finally, you don't need to set spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl to org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3AFileSystem; if you do things break as there is no NativeS3AFileSystem. Just use an s3a:// URL and let things sort it out for themselves (the binding is declared in hadoop-common/core-default.xml)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. it worked by having a proper maven dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Taking Steve's advice, this is what solved it for me in the end:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```